# jquery validation for form fields

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

Sometimes I just wish I was not a web developer. And this is one of those moments. I have a form.. and I need to validate this for fields such as number fields like postcode, phone numbers etc.

Now. here is the URL 
http://bit.ly/YXjsdb

Steps:

> - Go to the URl http://bit.ly/YXjsdb
> - Add any products to the basket
> - Go to the basket
> - Put any address inside the guest checkout field
> - Try adding address by clicking on Add Address Field
> - A pop up address book should pop up

.
I need the fields **"postcode" and "phone number"** to be only number fields. Any other things input there should send an error message straight to the "formError" place.

Any help please. I am really confused on how to do this. It seems to be using jQuery validation. But I am just confused. Maybe I will wake up tomorrow and look at this with clear brain and find the solution right away. Any pretty help from anyone?

```
var ValidatingForm = new Class({
    Implements:[EventProxy, Options],
    options: {
        submit: 'defaultSubmit'
    },
    setupForm: function(selector, options) {

        this.options.submit = $.proxy(this, 'defaultSubmit');
        if (options) {
            this.setOptions(options);
        }
        this.form = jQuery(selector);
        this.el = selector;
        this.form.on('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        this.form.find('.formError').val(' ');
        $(this.el + ' input').addClass('text ui-widget-content');
        $(this.el + ' select').addClass('ui-widget-content');
        $(this.el + ' button').addClass('ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only');
        $(this.el + ' input:checkbox').addClass('ui-widget-content');

        var self = this;
        this.form.validate({
            submitHandler: this.options.submit,
            showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
                if (this.errorList.length) {
                    self.showFormError('Fields marked * are required');
                }
                for ( var i = 0; this.errorList[i]; i++ ) {
                    var error = this.errorList[i];
                    $(error.element).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
                }
                if (this.settings.unhighlight) {
                    for ( var i = 0, elements = this.validElements(); elements[i]; i++ ) {
                        this.settings.unhighlight.call( this, elements[i], this.settings.errorClass, this.settings.validClass );
                    }
                }
            },
            highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
                $(element).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
            },
            unhighlight: function(input) {
                $(input).removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
            }
        });
    },
    resetForm: function() {
        this.form.find('.formError').empty();
        this.form.find('.formError').append('&nbsp;');
        this.form.validate().resetForm();
        $(this.el + ' input').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
        $(this.el + ' select').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
    },
    showFormError: function(errorMessage) {
        this.form.find('.formError').empty();
        this.form.find('.formError').append(errorMessage);
    },
    defaultSubmit: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: not a single piece of code ? what have you tried ?

Comment: hmm I guess I should provide my error validation code so far ehy? As I said I am really tired.. and anyway... added what I have so far in the question itself

Comment: Please avoid the shortened URLs

Answer (score 0):

How about using the following code: Just use the code as **validator.validateNumbers(number1)**

> var validator = new function () {
>
> ```
> this.validatePassowrds = function (pwd, cpwd) {
>     if (pwd == cpwd) {
>         return true;
>     } else {
>         return false;
>     }
> };
>
> this.validateNumbers = function (num) {
>     var pattern = /^[0-9]+$/g;
>     if (num == num.match(pattern))
>         return true;
>     else
>         return false;
> };
>
> this.validateAlphabets = function (alp) {
>     var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/g;
>     if (alp == alp.match(pattern))
>         return true;
>     else
>         return false;
> };
>
> this.validateEmail = function (email) {
>     var pattern = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
>     if (email.match(pattern) != null && email.match(pattern) != "") {
>         return true;
>     } else {
>         return false;
>     }
> };
>
> this.validateNonEmpty = function (field) {
>     if (field.length > 0)
>         return true;
>     else
>         return false;
> };
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

add `pattern="^[0-9]+$"` to your form field.
Keep in mind that if you have international customers that they have letters in their postal code(dutch for exampel is 0000 AA format)

Dutch validation of postcal code can be done with `^[0-9]{4}[ ][A-Z]{2}$`

I have this javascript for when the country select field changes:

`<select onchange="if(this.selectedIndex != 0){$('#postcode').attr('pattern','^.+$');}else{$('#postcode').attr('pattern','^[0-9]{4}[ ][A-Z]{2}$');}">`

in the title field of your `<input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]+$" name="postcode" id="postcode" title="The postal code may only contain numbers">` you can place the error message that they get to see if they try to submit and the entry is "illegal"

Comment: hey... great! I can totally use that!